# PHP get website root absolute URL in server?

Tags: php

I rely heavily in `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` to get absolute paths. However this doesn't work for sites which URLs don't point to the root.

I have sites stored in folders such as:

- site1
- site2

all directly inside the root. Is there a way to get the path in the server where the current site root is?

It should return:

```
   /var/chroot/home/content/02/6945202/html/site1 // If the site is stored in folder 'site1'
   /var/chroot/home/content/02/6945202/html // If the site is stored in the root
```

Comment: Do you want to get the document's root from the root of domain or what? Coz, what you are doing is actually right!

Comment: I want to get the absolute path on the server where each site is hosted.

Comment: Okay, `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` actually does it, but what is it you are getting? You have given what you want. I guess you need Apache's help for this, because only Apache knows which is the Virtual Host and its address. Get it?

Comment: Nope, are you saying it's not possible with php to know where the site root is? Interestingly `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` echoes `/` when executed in '/site1'. Indicating it considers it to be the root.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simply append `dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])` to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

**Update**

The website seems to be directory "mounted" on that folder, so `SCRIPT_NAME` will obviously be `/`.

So, to make this work you have to use either `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` to find out where your script is located in the file system.

**Update 2**

There's no single `index.php` controller for the whole site, so that won't work either.

The following expression does a string "subtraction" to find the common path. You have a known prefix (document root), an unknown (the root folder) and a known suffix (the script path), so to find the first two, you take the full absolute path (`__FILE__`) and subtract the known suffix:

```
substr(__FILE__, 0, -strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

If included files need this value, you must store this in a constant first before including the dependent scripts. .

Comment: I tried running that in site2 index.php and it returns: `/`. I need it to point to: `/var/chroot/home/content/02/6945202/html/site1` which is the my site's root.

Comment: Looks like your server is chrooted, which may be affecting the variables being passed to PHP. Is that path your server account root directory?

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that the site gets referred to as `http://www.example.org/index.php`; in that case you must use `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)` and keep that in a constant so that included scripts can also use it.

Comment: No, my server account root directory is `/var/chroot/home/content/02/6945202/html`. mk-ds.com (one of my sites) points to this folder `/var/chroot/home/content/02/6945202/html/mkds`. So the site's root is actually `/mkds` I need a way to echo either path depending where what the site's root is.

Comment: @Liso22 right, so then you have to use my second suggestion in the answer

Comment: But I don't need the absolute directory of the current file. EG: If I am in `mkds.com/apis/f.php` with `__FILE__` I would get: `/var/chroot/home/content/02/6945202/html/mkds/apis/f.php` and what I need is just `/var/chroot/home/content/02/6945202/html/mkds`

Comment: This will produce unexpected results (update2) if that line is inside and include file e.g. if file containing the line is called `setting.php` and you like to use it from index.php, you'll get incorrect string

Comment: @AaA yeah, this concern is covered in the last sentence "If included files need this value, you must store this in a constant first before including the dependent scripts"

Comment: Guess my comment wasn't clear either. I meant the other way. If value is calculated in include file and used in a page, we will still get wrong value. Since we know where the include file is located in relation to root of our web, a hardcoded relative path string should solve the issue. something like `define("PHYSICAL_ROOT", str_replace('Relative_Path_of_this_file_to_root','', dirname(__FILE__)));`

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers, this also works for me

```
substr(substr(__FILE__, strlen(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))), 0, - strlen(basename(__FILE__)));
```

Comment: Your solution is based on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, which has proven to be platform dependent: in some cases it is compiled with the path to the server root, in other cases with the path to the site root, so it is not safe. I think the best way is to rely on `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `getcwd()` for the current absolute server path of the folder the current script is in.

You can define a constant at the top of your website so that the rest of the website can rely on that path.

```
define('MY_SERVER_PATH', getcwd());
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following method to get the absolute root url from your server settings

```
   str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/",$_SERVER['PHPRC'],$_SERVER['REAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
```

or use the [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php). it gets the current working directory of your application

Comment: Neither `PHPRC` nor `REAL_DOCUMENT_ROOT` exist on my rather standard PHP 7 (Fedora 25) installation.