# Links not working from subdirectories

Tags: php, html, home-directory

I want to make multiple pages on my website, but to keep everything clean I want to make different directoriess with the different pages. However, I use php to make a different file with my header that is included in all my pages, so I only have to change the code of my header once and it will be the same on all pages.

The problem is that the links I use in my menu items (like home, contact, about, etc.) will not work anymore when you're on a page inside a directory (I'll make an example below).

So my question:
Is there a home folder on a website (like ~/ on unix) or is there another way to make it work?

Example of my directory structure:

```
htdocs
    index.php
    header.php
    menus
        contact.php
        about.php
```

(a link to index.php won't work anymore if you're on the contact.php page)

Comment: If you put / at the front of a link, it starts from the domain name. So, if I am in http://example.com/some/lower/dir and I go to foo.html, it will go to http://example.com/some/lower/dir/foo.html. If, I go to /foo.html, it will go to http://example.com/foot.html. I can force a subdir by using /another/dir/foo.html.

Comment: *"(a link to index.php won't work anymore if you're on the contact.php page)"* - So, where's your code?

Comment: I'd sure like to get a response from that ^

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. I've asked for clarification but haven't seen an update to the question, nor was the comment I left responded to; the vote to close IMHO is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're using relative paths in your menu links.  Use an [absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls) instead by starting with a "/":

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="/menus/about.php">About</a>
```

or a complete URL:

```
<a href="http://example.com/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="http://example.com/menus/about.php">About</a>
```

Comment: Agreed that could work, yet I have seen questions in the past where they had to use the full system address (if local) and the OP didn't post any code or if used on a hosted service or local. If "local", then my comment should be taken into consideration.

Comment: Also, this: `<a href="../index.php">Home</a>` should work.

Comment: @SumutiuMarius No it will not.  The menu needs to work from within any subdirectory.

Comment: @MattS Sure. It depends of the environment.

Comment: Thanks @MattS Another and what I meant was `<a href="/var/home/public/index.php">Home</a>` type of thing. Then there's the server's root as per  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10925538/1415724 - This thing could go either way *lol*

Comment: Oh yeah.  I build my systems to avoid such things.  But you're right, until we see the code it's hard to say...

Comment: @MattS yeah, I asked them about it [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029394/links-not-working-from-subdirectories#comment75085430_44029394) but they've yet to respond, unless they're not bothering and just want answers/solutions, or have logged off. Maybe it's lunchtime over there.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had tried this before but it didn't work, now I found why: I'm using a localhost on my laptop as a test server and inside my htdocs I have different maps with my different websites, so it was pointing to the htdocs map instead of the "home" folder of that particular website

Answer (score 0):

The home directory of a website can be accessed with a simple '/' at the start of the link you want to add. From there you can enter subfolders by appending the folder name.

Example:
'example.com/subfolder/subsubfolder/page.html'